# What is the canonical way to find out if a Django model is saved to db?

Tags: django, django-models

I generally check `if obj.pk` to knwo if the objects is saved. This wont work however, if you have `primary_key = True` set on some fields. Eg I set `user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)` on my `UserProfile`.

What is the canonical way to find out if a Django model is saved to db?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Important Note (as of 6 May '19): If your models use UUID fields (or other method of internal ID generation, use `self._state.adding` as mentioned in the comments.**

Actually,`obj.pk` is the most canonical way. Django itself often doesn't "know" if the object is saved or not. According to [the django model instance reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert), if there is a primary key set already, it checks on`save()` calls by selecting for the id in the database before any insert.

Even if you set `user = models.OneToOneField(..., primary_key=True)` the `.pk` attribute will still point to the correct primary key (most likely `user_id`) and you can use it and set it as if it was the same property.

If you want to know after an object has been saved, you can catch the [post_save signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save). This signal is fired on model saves, and if you want you can add your own application-specific attribute to the model, for example `obj.was_saved = True`. I think django avoids this to keep their instances clean, but there's no real reason why you couldn't do this for yourself.  Here is a minimal example:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from myapp.models import MyModel

def save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.was_saved = True

post_save.connect(save_handler, sender=MyModel)
```

You can alternately have this function work for *all* models in your app by simply connecting the signal without specifying the `sender=` argument.  Beware though, you can create undefined behaviours if you override a property on someone else's model instance that you are importing.

Comment: there is a boolean kwarg `created` in the post save signal by default, so no need to insert your own.

Comment: For modern Django, it should be noted that this does not work when you're using your own primary key fields with a default value generator like a UUIDField or other method of generating ids.  As noted in other answer, you should use `self._state.adding`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19379636/23972

Answer (score 56):

Nowadays you can check for:

```
self._state.adding
```

This value is set by the `QuerySet.iterator()` for objects which are not added yet in the database. You can't use this value in the `__init__()` method yet, as it's set after the object is constructed.

Comment: Thank you I did not know this existed worked on Django 1.8 (Python 3.x)

Comment: It gets even better in Django 1.8, now there is `Model.from_db()`

Comment: this should be the currently accepted answer, because checking for the primary key doesn't work if you use UUID fields, because those are automatically generated when an instance is created.

Comment: `self._state.adding == True` means "not added yet in the database". See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/

Comment: Care to explain how `Model.from_db()` is relevant here?

Answer (score 10):

Lets say `obj` is an instance of `MyModel`. Then we could use the following block of code to check if there already is an instance with that primary key in the database:

```
if obj.pk is None:
    # Definitely doesn't exist, since there's no `pk`.
    exists = False
else:
    # The `pk` is set, but it doesn't guarantee exists in db.
    try:
        obj_from_db = MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
        exists = True
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        exists = False
```

This is better than checking whether `obj.pk is None`, because you could do

```
obj = MyModel()
obj.pk = 123
```

then

```
obj.pk is None  # False
```

This is even very likely when you don't use the autoincrement `id` field as the primary key but a natural one instead.

Also, prior to Django 4.1, there was another case where `obj.pk is None` might be unreliable: As Matthew pointed out in the comments, you could do

```
obj.delete()
```

after which you still have

```
obj.pk is None  # False
```

(In Django 4.1, `obj.delete()` sets `obj.pk` to `None`.)

Comment: This answer helped me b/c I found that .pk was still set after a delete(). Thank you.

Comment: At some point Django started setting `id` to `None` after delete. I encountered this with Django 4.2.4. I'm not sure when this was changed. The 4.1 documentation notes that `id` is set to None. The 4.0 documentation does not. But the 4.1 release notes don't seem to mention this change, so I don't know when it changed.

Answer (score 5):

@Crast's answer was good, but I think incomplete. The code I use in my unit tests for determining if an object is in the database is as follows. Below it, I will explain why I think it is superior to checking if `obj.pk is None`.

## My solution

```py3
from django.test import TestCase
class TestCase(TestCase):
    def assertInDB(self, obj, msg=None):
        """Test for obj's presence in the database."""
        fullmsg = "Object %r unexpectedly not found in the database" % obj
        fullmsg += ": " + msg if msg else ""
        try:
            type(obj).objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
        except obj.DoesNotExist:
            self.fail(fullmsg)

    def assertNotInDB(self, obj, msg=None):
        """Test for obj's absence from the database."""
        fullmsg = "Object %r unexpectedly found in the database" % obj
        fullmsg += ": " + msg if msg else ""
        try:
            type(obj).objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
        except obj.DoesNotExist:
            return
        else:
            self.fail(fullmsg)
```

Notes: Use the above code with care if you use custom managers on your models name something other than `objects`. (I'm  sure there's a way to get Django to tell you what the default manager is.) Further, I know that `/assert(Not)?InDB/` are not a PEP 8 method names, but I used the style the rest of the `unittest` package used.

## Justification

The reason I think `assertInDB(obj)` is better than `assertIsNotNone(obj.pk)` is because of the following case. Suppose you have the following model.

```py3
from django.db import models
class Node(models.Model):
    next = models.OneToOneField('self', null=True, related_name='prev')
```

`Node` models a doubly linked list: you can attach arbitrary data to each node using foreign keys and the tail is the `Node` *obj* such that `obj.next is None`. By default, Django adds the SQL constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the primary key of `Node`. Now, suppose you have a `list` *nodes* of length *n* such that `nodes[i].next == nodes[i + 1]` for *i* in [0, *n* - 1). Suppose you call `nodes[0].delete()`. In my tests on Django 1.5.1 on Python 3.3, I found that `nodes[i].pk is not None` for *i* in [1, *n*) and only `nodes[0].pk is None`. However, my `/assert(Not)?InDB/` methods above correctly detected that `nodes[i]` for *i* in [1, *n*) had indeed been deleted.

Comment: This will be true for all versions of Django and Python because the items in your `nodes` list are instantiated model objects, and therefore no longer affected by anything which happens in the database. Checking for `pk is not None` does at least tell you if the instance had *at some point* been saved to the db (...assuming no one manually assigned a value to `pk` on the instance)

Comment: A better alternative for `assertInDb` would be: `obj.refresh_from_db()`, and for `assertNotInDb`: `with self.assertRaises(obj.DoesNotExist): obj.refresh_from_db()`.